# Does API-gateway use to facilitate the rest API to communicate with micro-services?

Tags: rest, api, docker, microservices, api-gateway

I am developing a website using which is based on a microservices architecture which is containerized with docker. Now I want to communicate with microservices using rest API. I read some articles which show some diagrams that API gateway make some connections to microservices. I am confused about the main purpose of the API gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Gateways are used for cross cutting concerns like authentication,  logging and redirect to respective backend services.  They are usual the single point of entry for applications and are exposed publicly.  the rest of the services can sit behind the firewall that your gateway has access to making backend services secure. you also write your resiliency logic in the gateway by implementing retry or circuit breaker patterns etc.

Since gateway has advantages but it can be single point of failure.  so make sure it's highly available by deploying redundant copies